# mysql to select messages i have sended or recieved from others

Tags: php, mysqli, pdo, sqlite

I am new to coding,

I want to select messages that I sent or received from others.
This is my table:

Messages:

```
'id' // primary id, auto increment
'from_id' // user id who sent message
'to_id' // friend id who received message
'to_name' //name  who received message
'to_email' // email who received message
'message' // message
'chat_time' //
```

What W want is like the Facebook inbox .... list messages send by me or received by me.

I tried this code , but it's showing all data's:

```
SELECT * FROM messages where to_id=:uid 
   UNION ALL
       SELECT  * FROM messages WHERE from_id = :uid
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_id = :uid OR from_id = :uid
```

no need to use UNION here.

Comment: That could mean that all the rows in the table have either send by you or received by you. Can you add to your question sample data that is returned but does meet the criteria?